# Layout for my error pages - CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.1, cakephp-2.3

According to the CakePHP 2.x [cookbook](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/exceptions.html#exception-renderer):

By default `app/Layouts/default.ctp` layout is used for error pages.

If you want to use another layout `app/Layouts/my_error.ctp` for your error pages, then simply edit the error views and add the statement `$this->layout = 'my_error'` to the `error400.ctp` and `error500.ctp`.

So, I would like to use custom layouts for my error pages. Can someone show me the code examples of how can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just write `$this->layout = 'my_error'` in your error400.ctp and error500.ctp files

Comment: yes, you can check it on http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html

You can create as many layouts as you wish: just place them in the app/View/Layouts directory, and switch between them inside of your controller actions using the controller or view’s $layout property: